# Migrated question doesn't show author in the "recent questions" view

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, recent-activity

*I haven't found a duplicate, though it seems to happen for all migrated questions.*

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/134754/how-unique-is-a-windows-product-key) has just been migrated from SO to SU, and doesn't show its author in the "recent questions" page.

[image: screenshot]

I guess it's because there is no "last activity" recorded on SU, but the timestamp still shows, so I guess the author should as well. Especially that this user has an account on SU as well.

Not really a blocking thing, but just reporting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some background on why this happened.

On the home page and certain [question listing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active), we display the user and timestamp of the last activity on questions.

Last activity is *primarily* * any asking, answering, or editing that happens on a question or its answers.  When activity occurs, we update two fields on the question record:

```
LastActivityDate (datetime, null)
LastActivityUserId (FK, int, null)
```

The issue you reported showed up because, **at the time of migration, the question owner did not exist on SU.**  After seeing the question was migrated, [the owner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe) created his SU account and then associated to SO; question ownership was also resolved during account association.

What was not done was setting the `LastActivityUserId` during the account association process - we can fix that, but most users with migrated questions aren't as diligent as [Uwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe) in creating new site accounts to tend their migrated questions.  **So this issue will still persist most of the time.**

Thank you for reporting it, though - we can still make migration/association a little bit better :)

<sub>* starting a bounty also updates last activity</sub>

Comment: The small fix will be pushed to all sites tonight.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation (and fast part of fix).

Comment: I just found [another one](http://superuser.com/questions/141693/drawing-lattices-online) a few minutes ago. Shows fine [in the complete list](http://img.skitch.com/20100516-qtbr3yrwqaf7fwi7rq32x576b5.png), but is missing the author [on the home page](http://img.skitch.com/20100516-q2xssp6j5b2941gdp442q96u4j.png). Does this imply that "the small fix" didn't work? If I recall correctly, then Community used to be shown for the last activity?

Comment: And, @Jarrod, do you think missing authors **in the revision history** might be related as well? [This](http://superuser.com/posts/141850/revisions) migrated history [shows no name](http://img.skitch.com/20100516-c5jmy1w14hjgytfc7xmyujtdw5.png), while the author (who answered at Stack Overflow) is actually also known at Super User, and shows fine [below the answer itself](http://img.skitch.com/20100516-1e27b5nsrtswnypkaiqx4k8xj3.png).

Comment: Noticed this behavior still occurring.  Is there any plan to update it?