# Last activity name missing from migrated question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, question-activity

[question listing on front page with no user name http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2417/capture11.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2417/capture11.png)

According to its [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/59175/timeline) the last activity was mine (I posted an answer). However, I answered it on Stack Overflow before its migration here. Maybe it is the cause of this display bug?

---

**Edit**: this was erroneously closed by a mod as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47859/migrated-question-doesnt-show-author-in-the-recent-questions-view), however as it becomes clear after reading the [Jarrod's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47859/migrated-question-doesnt-show-author-in-the-recent-questions-view/47888#47888) it is **not**:

- Jarrod Dixon ♦ posted that the other issue was caused by the fact that "at the time of migration, the question owner did not exist on SU". This is obviously not the case here since I've had an account on SO and MSO for over half a year.
- The issue is `status-completed` and Jarrod Dixon ♦ said that the field will be updated if the user registers an account on the website the question was migrated to; but again, this is a whole different bug.

Comment: Don't forget to read the part of the bug report that says "Especially that this user has an account on SU as well."

Comment: @random: According to Jarrod's answer, the account hadn't yet been created when that question was migrated. This does seem like a different issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

This should no longer happen as a result of a *complete* overhaul of the migration system a while back.  How migrations are handled has been almost completely changed...making this and other potential problems a non-issue.

Comment: A note to those wondering why the question was bumped: this answer was just downvoted today, which pushed it to a score of 0 and made the question eligible for Community bumps as a question with only zero-score answers. Incidentally, less than an hour after the downvote, the Community user bumped this question.

Comment: @Sonic no worry, this has been fixed with another upvote. ;)